# undefined reference to ‘_imp__InitBizLib’

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, dll, mingw

I am getting the error above when trying to use a 3rd party SDK with a C++ program written using eclipse on XP.  Based on searches I understand that this error is caused by the linker not correctly pointing to the .dll or .lib.  I have included the path to these items in the Environmental Variable - PATH, and also in eclipse under Properties\C/C++ Build\Settings\MinGW C++ Linker\Libraries.  The path used for both of these items is C:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK

Here is the console output:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -IC:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lm -v -o src\BizScan.o ..\src\BizScan.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' 'C:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-o' 'src\BizScan.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -I C:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/ -dD ..\src\BizScan.cpp -quiet -dumpbase BizScan.cpp -mtune=i386 -march=i386 -auxbase-strip src\BizScan.o -g3 -O0 -Wall -version -fmessage-length=0 -o C:\DOCUME~1\Game\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccwufpbm.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.6.1 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=64 --param ggc-min-heapsize=65307
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/mingw32
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/backward
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.6.1 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=64 --param ggc-min-heapsize=65307
Compiler executable checksum: 8e56a7b4b7f3db333ff95dd4b2d788a4
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' 'C:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-o' 'src\BizScan.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -o src\BizScan.o C:\DOCUME~1\Game\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccwufpbm.s
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../;/mingw/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' 'C:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-o' 'src\BizScan.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
g++ -LC:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK -lm -o HelloWorld.exe src\HelloWorld.o src\BizScan.o
src\BizScan.o: In function `ZN7BizScan4InitEv':
C:\Documents and Settings\Game\workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/BizScan.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp__UseFixedModel'
C:\Documents and Settings\Game\workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/BizScan.cpp:22: undefined reference to `_imp__SetTwainScanner'
C:\Documents and Settings\Game\workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/BizScan.cpp:23: undefined reference to `_imp__InitScanLib'
C:\Documents and Settings\Game\workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/BizScan.cpp:27: undefined reference to `_imp__InitImageLib'
C:\Documents and Settings\Game\workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/BizScan.cpp:31: undefined reference to `_imp__InitBizLib'
src\BizScan.o: In function `~BizScan':
C:\Documents and Settings\Game\workspace\HelloWorld\Debug/../src/BizScan.cpp:39: undefined reference to `_imp__UnInitScanLib'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 5648  ms.
```

Here is BizScan.cpp:

```
/*
 * BizScan.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 13, 2012
 *      Author: TFB
 */

#include "BizScan.h"
#include "slibexp.h" // ScanLib SDK header file
#include "..\header_lib\BizExp.h" // ScanLib SDK header file
#include "..\header_lib\ImageExp.h" // ScanLib SDK header file
#include "CSSN.h"
#include "windef.h"

BizScan::BizScan() {
    BizScan::Init();
}

const char* BizScan::Init() {
    UseFixedModel(11);
    const char *scannerSelected = "WIA-A6 Scanner 735";
    int result = SetTwainScanner(scannerSelected);
    result = InitScanLib(CSSN::GetSDKLicense().c_str());
    if(result < 0 && result != -13){
        return ScannerErrors(result);
    } else {
        result = InitImageLib(CSSN::GetSDKLicense().c_str());//initialize Image Lib SDK
        if(result < 0 && result != -13)//if error
            return ImageErrors(result);//call image lib sdk

        result = InitBizLib(CSSN::GetSDKLicense().c_str());//initialize Biz Card Lib Scanner SDK
        if(result < 0 && result != -13)//if error
            return BizErrors(result);//call biz card scanner Lib SDK error handler
    }
    return "Successful Initialization !!";
}

BizScan::~BizScan() {
    UnInitScanLib();
}
```

Here is BizScan.h:

```
/*
 * BizScan.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 13, 2012
 *      Author: TFB
 */

#ifndef BIZSCAN_H_
#define BIZSCAN_H_

#include "windef.h"

typedef HINSTANCE hDLL;

class BizScan {
private:

public:
    BizScan();
    virtual ~BizScan();
    const char* Init() ;
};

#endif /* BIZSCAN_H_ */
```

And here is the relevant part of slibexp.h:

```
/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// SLibExp.h
//
// Card Scanning Solutions (LLC)
// All Rights Reserved
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
#ifndef SLIBEXP_H
#define SLIBEXP_H


#ifdef SDLL
#define SDLL_EXP __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define SDLL_EXP __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

// Functions Prototypes
#if defined __cplusplus || defined c_plusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif

SDLL_EXP void UseFixedModel(int val);
SDLL_EXP short SetTwainScanner(const char *szStr);
SDLL_EXP short InitScanLib(const char * license);
IMAGE_EXPORT short InitImageLib(const char *licanse);
SDLL_EXP short UnInitScanLib();

#if defined __cplusplus || defined c_plusplus
}; 
#endif

#endif  /* SLIBEXP_H */
```

The other two methods, referenced in the console output both are defined in other header files that are in the same folder (the project root directory).  These are defined as follows:

```
IMAGE_EXPORT short InitImageLib(const char *licanse);
extern "C" BIZ_EXPORT short InitBizLib(const char *license);
```

Is there another place I need to link these .dll's.  I have tried using the LoadLibrary() method, but that method gets rejected for not being part of the scope.  How should I link to these dll's?  Thank you for any direction you may offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output you show, this is the relevant command:

```
g++ -LC:\Program Files\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK -lm -o HelloWorld.exe src\HelloWorld.o src\BizScan.o
```

It includes the path to the library, but there is no reference ro the actual library itself. I don't know what the name of the library is, but let's assume it's `libBizLib.a`, there should be `-lBizLib` at the end of that command; or if you want to link against the dll, you can use its full name (without `-l`).

(By the way, you mention a .lib extension of the library. That usually indicates a Visual Studio library. Are you sure the version you have, is compatible with MinGW?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It did end up being a result of the library being compiled with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue happened to me recently.  It appears to be because of the difference in compilers.  Where the library was built with one version of MinGW w64, my version is different enough that I can't compile in the .a file that came with the library.

But you can use dll's at runtime using LoadLibrary, but you then have to be more explicit when calling it.  Then the main ways the dll won't load is if the file isn't in the dll load path or if the dll is the wrong bit type (32 bit v 64 bit).

Hope that helps.